# How to make a multi-touch Chrome App

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-touch, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to make a Chrome App multi-touch?

I've been searching for a while, and at the Chrome Platform JavaScript API documentation I couldn't find anything related to touch gestures, swipe, zoom, rotate, etc.

I've just found [JavaScript touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) and the [Touchy](http://touchyjs.org/) jQuery library. Touchy is what I'm looking for, but I think that it just works for mobile browsers or enabling an Android emulator in Chrome (not so professional and maybe won't work in a Chrome App).

So, if you know a way of enabling multi-touch events in a Chrome App, please tell me.

Comment: On-topic, I don't know why you were so severely downvoted. But there is nothing special about Chrome Apps with regards to multitouch since, as you noticed, there's nothing in the API for that. I don't have first-hand experience, but it seems like the methods you stated are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is: yes. It is possible. The javascript touch events work in chrome apps as they do in a normal browser. They work on desktop (Windows, ChromeOS etc.) Obviously you need a touch screen :)

From your update I assume you are asking about chrome apps on ChromeOS / desktop. I am guessing Cordova / mobile chrome apps work with multi touch as well but am not sure.

If you're having problems making it work perhaps you could provide some code samples and describe what does and doesn't work.